# Printing a Dict() with Rich

Tags: python, rich

I'm trying to print a `dict()` using Pythons Rich. From my understanding, this should output the data on different lines etc. A bit like `pprint`.

But I'm getting:

```
>>> from rich import print
>>> print(output)

{'GigabitEthernet0/1': {'description': '## Connected to leaf-2 ##', 'type': 'iGbE', 'oper_status': 'up', 
'phys_address': '5000.0009.0001', 'port_speed': 'auto speed', 'mtu': 1500, 'enabled': True, 'bandwidth': 1000000, 
'flow_control': {'receive': False, 'send': False}, 'mac_address': '5000.0009.0001', 'auto_negotiate': True, 
'port_channel': {'port_channel_member': False}, 'duplex_mode': 'auto', 'delay': 10, 'accounting': {'other': {'pkts_in':
0, 'chars_in': 0, 'pkts_out': 431258, 'chars_out': 25875480}, 'ip': {'pkts_in': 513383, 'chars_in': 42910746, 
'pkts_out': 471188, 'chars_out': 45342027}, 'dec mop': {'pkts_in': 0, 'chars_in': 0, 'pkts_out': 7163, 'chars_out': 
551551}, 'arp': {'pkts_in': 3845, 'chars_in': 230700, 'pkts_out': 3846, 'chars_out': 230760}, 'cdp': {'pkts_in': 72010,
'chars_in': 18866620, 'pkts_out': 79879, 'chars_out': 31221768}}, 'ipv4': {'10.1.1.5/30': {'ip': '10.1.1.5',  ...
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Rich uses information about your terminal to determine whether or not to print things on multiple lines. What terminal emulator are you running this in? It's possible you're running this in a "dumb" terminal that just doesn't provide enough information

Comment: Im using VScode.

Comment: is the output colored?

Comment: @felix001 so, you are running it on teh VScode terminal?

Comment: yep, output is color, and yes on the vscode termminal.

Comment: If you don't mind, which module generated the output?

Answer (score 6):

TL;DR If your dictionary turns out to be not a *dict*, make an explicit conversion.

---

From contents of your *dictionary* I assume your `output` is from network device configuration like Cisco IOS, I'm dark on these areas and can't quite figure out where you've got your data from.

There's chance that module or script you used to get `output` may have actually returned a `dict` looking type called [MappingProxyType](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.MappingProxyType).

I speculate this is why your text is colored but not prettified.

---

For example lets see what `rich.print` does with `str.__dict__`:

```py
>>> from rich import print
>>> print(str.__dict__)
```

This will look like this, just as yours.

[image]

Do note this is xfce4 Terminal running in WSL2, drawn to X410 X-server. A fully capable terminal.

This indeed looks like *plain* `dict`, but lets check what it actually is:

```py
>>> type(str.__dict__)
<class 'mappingproxy'>

>>> from types import MappingProxyType
>>> isinstance(str.__dict__, MappingProxyType)
True

>>> isinstance(str.__dict__, dict)
False
```

As you see, despite it's output looks like a dictionary, it's not.

`types.MappingProxyType` Is essentially a read-only dictonary which isn't necessarily a `dict`. Devs of 3rd party libraries like `rich` might have forgotten existence of such type. If that's the case, then `rich.print` will do what built-in `print()` would do: to call `__repr__`/`__str__` - now just treating it as mere string.

We can confirm this behavior by passing *string* that looks like `__repr__` of a method, and that still gets rich text treatment.

[image]

And also by creating instance of `MappingProxyType` yourself.

```py
>>> from types import MappingProxyType
>>> from rich import print

>>> data = {f"{n}": n for n in range(11)}

>>> print(data)
{
    '0': 0,
    '1': 1,
    '2': 2,
    '3': 3,
    '4': 4,
    '5': 5,
    '6': 6,
    '7': 7,
    '8': 8,
    '9': 9,
    '10': 10
}

>>> print(MappingProxyType(data))
{'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9,
'10': 10}
```

From which you can see how type affects `rich.print`'s output.

To fix, simply convert `types.MappingProxyType` to `dict`.

```py
>>> from rich import print
>>> print(dict(str.__dict__))
```

[image]

And that's way more pretty than it used to be - excluding `__doc__` value which is a single string and can't be helped.

Comment: Rich author here. This answer is probably correct. Your `output` may be dict like object, but not an actual dict. I would suspect a `UserDict` rather than a MappingProxy. If you could `print(type(output))` we would know for sure.